# Jquery - capture element by it's style property value and then change the value

Tags: jquery, css, dom

I have a div which I need to capture based on its "top" value of "614px" and then change that value to "300px" with jQuery. any thoughts?

```
<div class="small-12  large-3  columns " style="left: 443px; top: 614px; position: absolute;">
```

Comment: I guess your request with Jquery is because you can't change that class on CSS ... or target the element by classname. ? Am I right?

Comment: By "capture", do you mean target this specific element regarding its css top property value?

Comment: Correct, the only way I can target this div is by its "top" value in the inline style. Any ideas on how do I achieve this? Or even insert a class via jQuery and then target it? it is the 6th item in a div with a unique ID so maybe I could target it like that?

Comment: sorry for the wrong word - yes, I basically need to change the "top" value of this DIV either by targeting it by its "top" value or as the 6th child of a DIV with a unique ID

Comment: So try `$('#divID').children('div).eq(5).css('top',300);` But it could be a XY problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Thanks @A.Wolff - That almost did the trick - but it captures the grandchild. The below answer solved my issue. Agreed on the XY problem, but the thing is I have a grid and it calculates coordinates of the div's. Chrome and Mozilla work fine, IE miscalculates so I need to do it like this (IE sucks) until I can find a better fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find a `div` that is *the 6th child of a DIV with a unique ID*. You can easily select it with that selector : `#uniqueID > :nth-child(6)`

You there, you can use CSS directly with `!important` to modify your value (not supported by IE8 and below):

```
#uniqueID > :nth-child(6){
    top : 300px!important;
}
```

Or use jQuery :

```
$('#uniqueID > :nth-child(6)').css('top', 300);
```

Comment: This works perfectly. However, how could I apply this only in the case the TOP value is say "415px"?

Comment: You can add a condition : `if($('#uniqueID > :nth-child(6)').css('top') === '415px')`.

Answer (score 0):

You should move the inline css to a class and then add the class to your div. This way you can target the div easily and take control using jquery.

Comment: Exactly, this is not the answer - I can't do that - that's why I'm trying to find a workaround.

Comment: But you could've mentioned "you can't move it to a class" in your question. I assumed you might not know about that.

Answer (score 0):

here is a example that i find in other answer

```
$('[class]').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('your css property') == 'the expected value';
  }
).corner();
```

and here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anthony_yuan/5fWjK/1/) that he put for the example

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery's attributeContainsWord selector to do this with css. [docs](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/)

I made a jsbin demonstrating this [here](http://jsbin.com/fupukoniqe/3/edit?html,js,output)

In your case it would be like this:

```
var el = $('[style~="top:"][style~="614px;"]');
var style = el.attr('style');
el.attr('style', style.replace('top: 614px', 'top: 300px'));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in jquery:

```
var top = $(".columns").css("top");
if(top=="614px")
{
$(".columns").css("top", "300px");
}
```

Hope this helps.